# Using bash to get multiple MYSQL records

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to get multiple records from a mysql database and output them on a single line in a text file I have

```
#!/bin/bash
result_storage="/tmp/book"
id=$(mysql --host=host --user=user --password=password --database=db -s -N -e "selectcount(*) from people")
echo -e "$id New" > $result_storage

id2=$(mysql --host=host --user=user --password=password --database=db -s -N -e "select count(*) from numbers")
sed '1 s|$|"$id2" Numbers|' -i $result_storage
```

however the sed part prints $id2 rather than the count from id2

basically at the end I want /tmp/book to read

12 people 10 numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
mysql --host=host --user=user --password=password --database=db -s -N -e "selectcount(*) from people; select count(*) from numbers;"
```

I haven't executed above but most probably it will work...

Comment: not working for me and doesn't allow me to put my on text in file like    echo -e "$id New" does

Comment: Will u please edit you question and show sample output you require

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
sed '1 s|$|"$id2" Numbers|' -i $result_storage
```

to

```
sed "1 s|$| $id2 Numbers|" -i $result_storage
```

should work, as bash needs double quotes to perform variable substitution.

Comment: very close but it outputs "10" members ie with the quotation marks 12 people"10" numbers

Comment: If you don't want the quotation marks, then simply remove them, as I did in my answer.